# NSString to TimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a NSString with the format `00:00:00.00` obtained originally from `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SS"];`

how can I take that string and convert it to a TimeInterval?

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: convert a NSString with the format 00:00:00.00 to a NSTimeInterval

Comment: do you need timeinterval as string?

Comment: No. I already have it as a string. I need it as a NSTimeInterval.

Comment: It's awkward converting from string, as the formats are locale-dependent. The only time you should convert from string is when you have text supplied by direct user input. Is that the case, or have you considered whether you can change your code to avoid such conversion?

Comment: You need a NSDate object.The date format is not a date, but an object that explain how to format a date.

Comment: Your problem is that NSDate is precisely that -- a DATE, with time added.  What you have is a TIME with no date, so you can't use NSDate unless you just assume, say, Jan 1, 2000 (which is not necessarily a bad approach).  But, in your case, if you're getting the time from an NSDateFormatter call, the better choice would be to use the NSDate parameter to that call, and just use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. was much simpler than I thought:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:finishTimeString];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [currentDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: Just as long as you're aware that parsing will fail if HH > 23.

Comment: I needed to use [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:00:00.00"]]; because the parser assumed the reference date was the year 2000, not the year 1970.

Answer (score 6):

If you're 100% absolutely positively sure this format won't ever change, then here's a quick'n'dirty solution using [one of the most useful classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in Cocoa:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeFromString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];

    int h, m, s, c;
    [scn scanInt:&h];
    [scn scanString:@":" intoString:NULL];
    [scn scanInt:&m];
    [scn scanString:@":" intoString:NULL];
    [scn scanInt:&s];
    [scn scanString:@"." intoString:NULL];
    [scn scanInt:&c];

    return h * 3600 + m * 60 + s + c / 100.0;
}
```