# How to compare two time from NSDate. Returning nil for nsdate when doing comparision. #debug my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here is the code:

```
// get current date/time
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    currentTime = [currentTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
    currentTime = [currentTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];
    currentTime = [currentTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date1= [formatter dateFromString:currentTime];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"5:00:00"];


    NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
    if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2"); 
    }
```

Here when I run the code I am getting date1 and date2 as nil, while I am properly getting the current time in 24 hour format. I had applied same date formatting while getting current time from [NSDate date] . What am I missing here?

EDIT 1: Fixed the typo and changed the title.

EDIT 2: As per suggestion, To compare Only the hour I can use:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit) fromDate:date1];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
```

EDIT 3: Changed the title, to match the exact requirements.

But I am not able to retrieve date1 from current time. It throws a garbage value .

Comment: Why are you setting the Style as well as a format? Infact, what are you actually trying to do here? Is it just an experiment with NSDate and date formatters or do you want to do something like "get the number of seconds we are into today"?

Comment: Actually I want to compare two times and check if the current time is past 5:00 AM.

Comment: applying just the dateFormat itself also gives me date1 and date2 as nil.

Comment: So ask that question because this is a "debug my code" question and is not the right way to go about doing what you want :-) You should use NSDateComponents which will give you access to just the hour.

Comment: Ok. I can attempt this. But untill I get a correct date I cannot get proper hour. NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit) fromDate:date1];
        
        NSInteger hour = [components hour];

Comment: Note that if you want to use the user's 12/24 setting you should not provide a dateFormat.  And you generally should not use both dateFormat and timeStyle.

Comment: I read some where to provide a 24 hour format , dateFormat should be HH:mm:ss , BUT getting date1 from current time in this case is returning me garbage value even if I don't use timeStyle.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvoting the issue?

Comment: I suspect: this is a "debug my code" question and is not the right way to go about doing what you want. A better question would be "how do I compare two times and check if the current time is past 5:00 AM"

Comment: Ok. Changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo:
`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];`
should be:
`[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];`

To compare two dates use:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"05:00:00"];

NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
}
```

If you only want to compare the hours:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:date1];
NSInteger date1Hour = date1Components.hour;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"05:00:00"];
NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:date2];
NSInteger date2Hour = date2Components.hour;

if(date1Hour > date2Hour) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
}
```

Comment: Bamn! My mistake. Ok. After correcting the typo, I get garbage values both in date1 and date2. date1= 2000-01-01 15:49:48 +0000 and date2= 1999-12-31 23:30:00 +0000, so I guess there is some problem, atleast date2 should have been #somedate #05:00:00 +0000. What should be the issue?

Comment: I have edited the question. You may have a look please.

Comment: I do have to get a relevant date for 5 AM string value . I am not getting how to retrieve that?

Comment: If the hour comparison is notwhat you want please update the wuestion to exactly whatyou require.

Comment: It exactly works fine. Thanks a bunch for the update!! I required the hour update only. :)